# AngularJS testing - promise from service won't resolve

Tags: node.js, angularjs, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

i have a service that returns a promise. i am trying to write a unit test for it but having issues. my first implementation:

```js
describe('Application Button Status Service', () => {
    let applicationBtnStatusService;

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestHelper().initApplicationModule();

      inject(($injector) => {
        applicationBtnStatusService = $injector.get('MwcApplicationBtnStatusService');
      });
    });

    it('CLDTX-22772: getStatusForAddDiskCloneBtn should return a promise resolving a button status', () => {
      const spy = spyOn(applicationBtnStatusService, 'getStatusForAddDiskCloneBtn').and.callThrough();

      const deferrdPromise = applicationBtnStatusService.getStatusForAddDiskCloneBtn(applicationDataMock);
      deferrdPromise.then((resolvedBtnStatus) => {
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus).toBeTruthy();
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus.btnDisabled).toBeDefined();
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus.disablingMessage).toBeDefined();
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus.btnDisabled).toBe(true);
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus.disablingMessage).toBe('Instance is running and in compatibility mode');
      });
    });
  },
);
```

this passes but it doesn't execute the `.then` of the promise. here is my second implementation:

```js
describe('Application Button Status Service', () => {
    let applicationBtnStatusService, rootScope, btnStatus;

    beforeEach(async (done) => {
      TestHelper().initApplicationModule();
      inject((
        MwcApplicationBtnStatusService: ApplicationBtnStatusService,
        $rootScope
      ) => {
        applicationBtnStatusService = MwcApplicationBtnStatusService;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
      });

      const resolvedBtnStatus = await applicationBtnStatusService.getStatusForAddDiskCloneBtn(applicationDataMock);
      rootScope.$apply();
      console.log('promise resolved', resolvedBtnStatus, '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n');
      btnStatus = resolvedBtnStatus;
      done();
    });

    it('CLDTX-22772: getStatusForAddDiskCloneBtn should return a promise resolving a button status', (done) => {
      console.log('btnStatus', btnStatus);
      expect(btnStatus).toBeDefined();
      done();
    });
  }
);
```

the second one fails with this error:

```
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0) Application Button Status Service CLDTX-22772: getStatusForAddDiskCloneBtn should return a promise resolving a button status FAILED
        Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        Expected undefined to be defined.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (app/application/services/application-btn-status-service/application-btn-status-service.spec.js:229:27)
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 269 of 269 (1 FAILED) (7.443 secs / 7.383 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 268 SUCCESS
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cloudistics-mwc@0.0.1 test: `npm run generate-responses && karma start karma.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cloudistics-mwc@0.0.1 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ryan.Waite\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-10T17_01_55_717Z-debug.log
```

and no matter what i change the default interval, the operations takes longer than it.

Comment: The `async` and `await` operators use ES6 promises. ES6 promises are not integrated with the AngularJS digest cycle. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Avoid ES6 promises and  use only $q service promises.

Comment: @georgeawg hey, that service does return a $q promise. when i console.log `deferredPromise`, i can see it in the terminal; it has value. it's just that it doesn't resolve. not sure how to get it to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

In your first solution, please inject `$rootScope` and then call `$rootScope.$digest` after async call.

```
it('CLDTX-22772: getStatusForAddDiskCloneBtn should return a promise resolving a button status', (done) => {
      const spy = spyOn(applicationBtnStatusService, 'getStatusForAddDiskCloneBtn').and.callThrough();

      const deferrdPromise = applicationBtnStatusService.getStatusForAddDiskCloneBtn(applicationDataMock);
      deferrdPromise.then((resolvedBtnStatus) => {
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus).toBeTruthy();
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus.btnDisabled).toBeDefined();
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus.disablingMessage).toBeDefined();
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus.btnDisabled).toBe(true);
        expect(resolvedBtnStatus.disablingMessage).toBe('Instance is running and in compatibility mode');
        done();
      });
      $rootScope.$digest();
    });
```

Comment: hey, that didn't work for me. i still got the async error.

Comment: Are you sure your function returns promise? Can you go into your coverage report and check what code is getting executed from service function?